# Derivative of special function

Tags: derivatives

I have the following formula and I would like to take the derivative of this function with respect to ***a*** where we know that $x$ is a vector of our data and $z$ is constant. how can I do this?

$$f(x) = \log\left(1 - {\left(e^{a\frac{x^2}{2}}\right)}^{e^{z}}\right)$$

Comment: It sounds like you want a partial derivative, or is $a$ dependent on $x$?

Comment: yes , I need a partial derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following:

$$
f(x, a) = \log\left(1 - e^{ae^z\frac{x^2}{2}}\right)\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial a} = \frac{-e^z\frac{x^2}{2}e^{ae^z\frac{x^2}{2}}}{1 - e^{ae^z\frac{x^2}{2}}} = -\frac{x^2e^z}{2\left(e^{-\frac{ax^2e^z}{2}} - 1\right)}
$$